# SCSS is not detected by Gramex

Tags: sass, gramex

SCSS files are not detected by `gramex` even after adding the handler(`ui.sass`).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check after updating nodejs.

Refer to this guide - [Nodejs installation/update on different OS](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version)